# MySql Java auto increment

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem with the auto incremented values in preparedStatement. Here is my database

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isbn` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `isbn` (`isbn`)
```

and here is my preparedStatement:

```
String title = fieldTitle.getText();
        String isbn = fieldISBN.getText();
        double price = Double.parseDouble(fieldPrice.getText());
        int pages = Integer.parseInt(fieldPages.getText());

        conn = DBUtil.connect();
        try {
            prepState = conn.prepareStatement("insert into book values(?,?,?,?)");

            prepState.setString(1, isbn);
            prepState.setString(2, title);
            prepState.setInt(3, pages);
            prepState.setDouble(4, price);

            prepState.execute();
```

However, when I fill in the fields I get the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. I know that when the field in the database is autoincremented I do not have to put it in the query...

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to explicitly name the columns you want to write to if you don't use all of them: `INSERT INTO book (isbn, title, pages, price) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Or an optional way is to pass null for the increment column. `INSERT INTO book values(null,?,?,?,?)`

Answer (score 0):

Modify you query to include column names:-

```
INSERT INTO  book (isbn, title, pages, price) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```